# Angular : how to stop duplicate item push in array?

Tags: javascript, angular

Here `data console` and this `data` push in `duplicatePushArray` but it once pushed I dont want to push again but if I push again i want to show same message second time also.

Ex. first time I push `2.jpg,3.jpg` now again I push `2.jpg,3.jpg` so it shows message like this `2.jpg,3.jpg value is already pushed please change this values` now again I push `2.jpg,3.jpg` so it shows message like this `2.jpg,3.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg value is already pushed please change this values` but i want to show message like this `2.jpg,3.jpg value is already pushed please change this values`

```
console.log(data); // (2) [{…}, {…}]0: {imageName: "2.jpg"}1: {imageName: "3.jpg"}
duplicatePushArray : any[] = [];
constructor(private snackBar : MatSnackBar) {}      

for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){
  if(this.duplicatePushArray.indexOf(data[i].imageName)) {
    this.duplicatePushArray.push(data[i].imageName);
    this.snackBar.open(this.duplicatePushArray+' '+ 'value is already pushed please change this values', '',{
      duration: 2000
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/mapset/

Comment: use `if(this.duplicatePushArray.indexOf(data[i].imageName) === -1) {`

Comment: @TamilSelvanC yes it not allow to push second time but i want to show message always when try to push again

Comment: I think you can use includes instead of indexOf or change the condition checking as @TamilSelvanC suggested

Comment: Do you want to push even if there a duplicate imageName?

Comment: No if duplicate imageName then not for ex. if 2.jpg and 3.jpg already pushed and now i push 2.jpg again then not allow to push

Comment: try `if(this.duplicatePushArray.indexOf(data[i].imageName) === -1) { this.duplicatePushArray.push(data[i].imageName); } else { this.snackBar.open(this.duplicatePushArray+' '+ 'value is already pushed please change this values', '',{
      duration: 2000
    }); }`

Comment: Why are you pushing and showing message inside the same condition?

Comment: @MahßußMØøn because in database that imageName already available so which name already in database i fetch now i want to show that name as message

Comment: Okay but the message should be inside the else condition. If not duplicate then push, else show message. Follow @Tamil Selvan C's Solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,1,2];
let duplicatePushArray = [];
for(let i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){
  if(duplicatePushArray.indexOf(data[i]) === -1) {
    duplicatePushArray.push(data[i]);
  } else {
    console.log(`${data[i]} is already pushed into array`);
  }
}

console.log('Final Array: ', duplicatePushArray)
```